# Xcode fix-it shortcut

Tags: xcode7, hotkeys

I am wondering is there any shortcut or hotkey that can apply the fix-it suggestion from Xcode? (Xcode 7)
In Android Studio, we can just use ctrl+enter to apply the correction. Is there anything similar to that in Xcode?
 some ref: 
https://swifteducation.github.io/assets/pdfs/XcodeKeyboardShortcuts.pdf

Answer (score 29):

In Xcode 8, this appears to now be 
`⌃⌥⌘F` or 
`Ctrl + Alt + Cmd + F`

If you want to change it, go to `Xcode` > `Preference` > `Key Bindings` and search for `Fix all in scope`.

Comment: This can also be found by Editor > Fix All in Scope

Comment: [Run all of Xcode's “Fix-it”s at once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505307/run-all-of-xcodes-fix-its-at-once)

Answer (score 26):

I am aware of two shortcuts.

`Ctrl + Cmd + '` - auto fix next error
`Ctrl + Cmd + "` - auto fix prev error

Enjoy!

Comment: This shortcut seems to consistently crash xcode 7.3.1

Answer (score 15):

**control** - **option** - **command** - **f**

`⌃`  `⌥` `⌘`  `f`

Then

`⌘` `enter`

To get out of split view.

Comment: Works but it brings assistant editor together at the same time

Comment: @Pei, what do you mean by "brings assistant editor together"?

Comment: @ScottyBlades it also shows `Assistant editor` of the `Xcode` which splits the code editor you know. kinda annoying

Comment: Its not doing that for me. Perhaps you can click `command` `enter` anytime that split view happens.

Answer (score 8):

Here are the default key bindings for XCode 8

[image]

Comment: This solution is awesome... but whenever I press the ctrl alt cmd F while fixing all issues, assistant editor shows up... turns out to be some bug in Xcode since 7... I changed this to ctrl+shift+f and works fine (it overlaps with some text edit function which I do not use)

Answer (score 4):

**Xcode Fix an issue**

Unlike `Android Studio` where you can apply a fix to a single issue, the `Xcode` are able to fix all issues at time via `Editor -> Fix All Issues`

[image]