# How to apply all suggestions made by Xcode, at once?

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm using Swift to develop an iOS app.
I just switched to Swift 3.0 and some parts of my code have not been converted automatically but Xcode still offers me suggestions to modify some of the lines of code. ( c.f. screenshot below )

Is there a way to apply all of these suggestions at once ?

[image]

Comment: If i remember right, when there is warnings you can select the yellow dot and then from there apply multiple, but i believe it would be per file. Id try that.

Comment: No there is none. It's a good exercise to resolve the issues manually. You will learn a lot about the new syntax of Swift 3.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Xcode fix-it shortcut](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34423765/xcode-fix-it-shortcut)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go to your issue navigator and highlight everything you want to fix. Then go to Editor -> Fix All in Scope.

Answer (score 4):

**command** - **option** - **control** - **f**

`⌘`   `⌥`  `⌃` `f`

Answer (score 1):

There are some keyboard shortcuts for fixing issues, specifically Jump and Fix Next Issue, keyboard command `⌃⌘'`

These should make things a bit faster even if they don't fix everything automatically.