# Quick way to fix Xcode warnings

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I've been switching between versions of Swift in Xcode 6 and my project now has 220 warnings.  Mostly minor code suggestions.

Is there an easy way in Xcode to run through all the warnings and use the "Fix-it" tool to auto correct it?

I would like to review each warning, then click a button to fix the warning, and then skip to next warning.  Otherwise it's going to take me a few hours to manually get through each warning.

Comment: Use Command+' to navigate to the next warning, review it, then hit Return to apply the auto-fix.  Repeat.

Comment: i'd use the "issue navigator" to click through the warning and call the quickfixes

Comment: Note: this is **not** a duplicate of [Run all of Xcode's “Fix-it”s at once](http://stackoverflow.com/q/32505307/77567), because TWilly wants to review each warning and Fix-it, not blindly apply them all.

Comment: @robmayoff how is this not a duplicate?  The solution is nearly identical, and your answer is nearly identical to the second answer in the dupe target.

Comment: Because the linked Q&A is about applying all Fix-its without individual review, but TWilly wants to review each Fix-it before applying it.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best bet is to use keyboard shortcuts. The default keyboard shortcut for Navigate > Jump to Next Issue is <kbd>⌘'</kbd> (command-single-quote). If you press it, Xcode will jump to the next issue it knows about. If that issue has a Fix-it available, the Fix-it popover will appear automatically and you can press return to execute the Fix-it, or press <kbd>⌘'</kbd> to leave the code unchanged and go to the next issue, or press escape to leave the code unchanged and stay on that issue.

You can also open the Issue Navigator (default shortcut: <kbd>⌘4</kbd>). Then you can click on issues one-by-one. If you click on an issue with a Fix-it, Xcode will show the Fix-it popover and you can press return to execute the Fix-it.

Comment: Return is doing nothing for me but dismissing the fix-it popup. Xcode 12.4. Does this still work for other people?

Comment: It hasn't worked for a while. Thanks, Apple.

Answer (score 1):

Previous answer is best solution,before doing it you must Fix **Validate project Settings** (*Update to recommended Settings*).Suppose you decided to fix it last,it may again arises some new warnings.

Answer (score 1):

**control** - **option** - **command** - **f**

`⌃`  `⌥` `⌘`  `f`

Just type

`⌘` `Enter`

afterward to adjust back to normal screens view.