# How to solve String interpolation produces a debug description for an optional value in XCode 8.3 without any changes in code

Tags: ios, swift, xcode8

I have updated the xcode 8.3 version and started getting the warnings shown in the image. It is asking me to change the code by providing the default values in the string. But the problem is that there are so many places in which this warning is. So if any one know the proper solution for solving it without any changes in code. Please let me know. Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Check this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/44917635/1753005

Answer (score -1):

Try to use the the `Fix All in Scope` option in the `Editor` menu.

[image: Fix All in Scope]

Image source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34571527/1283228

I'm not sure if it can fix all the errors and warnings in the project at once, but you should be able to fix all warnings in a file.