# iOS: Migration (Upgrade) from Swift 3 to Swift 4

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4, xcode9

Recent major update in iOS application development tool `Xcode 9` supports `Swift 3.2 & 4` programming language.

I've my app developed with Swift 3 version and I want to convert/migrate, complete source code from `Swift 3 to Swift 4`. During migration, it's showing me `354 errors`.

These errors are fixable. The solution of error is suggested by Xcode itself. But there are 354 errors. How can I fix them all at once? Manual fixing of each error one-by-one will be a time-consuming activity.

Is there any feasible solution to fix all errors at once.

Here is a snapshot with the sample.

[image]

Comment: If it's all the same errors, you could search & replace all occurrences in the workspace as a workaround.

Comment: I have that idea in my mind, several of them can be solved with such idea. But #selector statements expecting @objc with calling functions. That cannot be replaced with this idea

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32505307/run-all-of-xcodes-fix-its-at-once

Answer (score 19, accepted):

We have a better option to fix this error at once. It can be solved out from `Editor` menu

[image]

Use this option to fix all the error at once in class.

**Note:** You cannot always rely on Xcode suggestions, but for migration case it will work in most of the case.

Comment: How can it(this menu) be activated. It's remains inactive (not highlighted) in my Xcode.

Comment: select in the scope where you are having error... it will lighten up

Comment: what do you mean by "select in the scope"? I'm clicking around the damn editor and I cannot get it activated :/

Comment: @Krystian Did you found solution on this?

Comment: nope, I gave up. Waiting for JetBrains to implement this in AppCode.